# Не работает Функция changeFirstSymbol. Хэлп Гайс

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

Всем привет! Есть задачка: Дана строка. Сделайте заглавным первый символ каждого слова этой строки. Для этого сделайте вспомогательную функцию ucfirst, 
которая будет получать строку, делать первый символ этой строки заглавным и возвращать обратно строку с заглавной первой буквой.

Задачу надо решить разделяя каждую функцию отдельно и объявлять их в одной главной функции. Моя реализация примерно такая:

```
    <input type="text" class="input">


    let input = document.querySelector('.input');
    input.addEventListener('blur', changeFirstSymbol);

    changeFirstSymbol(input.value);

    function changeFirstSymbol(str) {
        getString(ucFirst(getArrayFromString(str)));
    }

    function getArrayFromString(str) {
        arr = str.split(' ');
        return arr;
    }

    function ucFirst(arr) {
        let newArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1);
        }
        return newArr;
    }

    function getString(arr) {
        str = arr.join(' ');
        return str;
    }
```

сonsole выдает следующую ошибку:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: str.split is not a function (main.js:12)
    at getArrayFromString (main.js:12)
    at HTMLInputElement.changeFirstSymbol (main.js:8)
```

Подскажите если есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в `input.addEventListener('blur', changeFirstSymbol);`. Дело в том, что вы не передали в функцию `changeFirstSymbol` параметр.

Посмотрите работающий пример.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input,.second-input');
console.log(inputs.length);
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    const result = changeFirstSymbol(inputs[i].value);
    console.log(result); // выводим результат в консоль
  });
}

function changeFirstSymbol(str) {
  const array = getArrayFromString(str);
  const arrayUCFirst = ucFirstArray(array);
  return getString(arrayUCFirst);
}

function ucFirstString(str) {
  return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}

function getArrayFromString(str) {
  return str.split(' ');
}

function ucFirstArray(arr) {
  const newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const str = ucFirstString(arr[i]);
    newArr.push(str);
  }
  return newArr;
}

function getString(arr) {
  return arr.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="second-input">
```

Comment: Ахахаха это смешно. Нет слов. И параметр он пытался передать  в `changeFirstSymbol`, но только другим способом. Так что это чистая ложь и клевета.

Comment: @Denis640Kb объяснения будут? Или вы просто тихо в сторонке посмеетесь?)

Comment: @Denis640Kb вы какой-то агрессивный. Но это ладно. И параметр ТС не пытался передать, он не понимает, что происходит в строчке `input.addEventListener('blur', changeFirstSymbol);`. А вы его код испортили :)

Comment: Как я понял чтобы работал changeFirstSymbol нужна еще одна функция которая ее обрабатывает. В данном случае анонимная. Классное решение. Я решил пойти дальше.         
<input type="text" class="input">
        <input type="text" class="second-input">

Comment: let input = document.querySelectorAll('.input .second-input');
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i].addEventListener('blur', function () {
                let result = changeFirstSymbol(input[i].value);
                console.log(result);
            });
        } И написать такое решение. Но оно не работает почему-то. Подскажите что можно сделать. Мне интересно именно момент инпутов с разными классами.

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев у вас неправильный селектор написан. Надо `.input,.second-input'`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я не агрессивный. Просто меня крайне забавляют подобные псевдо-гении. Вы одни в один как Эникейщик. Если бы я изменил вопрос - Вы поставили бы дизлайк за то, что я меняю когд автора, что кстати крайне не приветствуется в данном портале, если я ничего не буду менять - а просто исправлю имеющийся код - снова окажусь на Ваш взгляд не прав. И конечно же у Вас и на первый и на второй случай всегда найдётся "верное" решение.  Это называется двойными стандартами. А спорить с подобными людьми - себе дороже. И что касается второго события на кнопке - сам вопрос это исключал.

Comment: @Denis640Kb вы в первом предложении пишите, что не агрессивный. А во втором оскорбляете человека. Забавно.

Answer (score 1):

В целом почти всё правильно, есть только некоторые правки.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.input');
input.addEventListener('blur', changeFirstSymbol);

changeFirstSymbol(); // Тут не надо задавать параметр.

function changeFirstSymbol() {
    let v = input.value; //Параметр получаем в этой функции 
    let z = getString(ucFirst(getArrayFromString(v))); // получаем значения выполненных операций
    console.log(z); // выводим значение (Для демонстрации) А так можно записать и в input обратно и так далее
    return z;
}

function getArrayFromString(str) {
    let arr = str.split(' '); // не забываем let, так как в данной функции arr не была ещё объявлена, а через параметры она не передаётся
    return arr;
}

function ucFirst(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1);
    }
    return newArr;
}

function getString(arr) {
    let str = arr.join(' '); // Не забываем объявить переменную, так как в этой функции она ещё не была объявлена и не передавалась через параметры функции.
    return str;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Comment: Перенести получение значения из инпута в общую функцию - из разряда вредных советов :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вы бы хотябы сначала посмотрели что к чему. Не вынести из инпута, а получить значение в функции. При той передаче что была, данные передавались некорректно. Сначала попробуйте, потом критикуйте. Хотя Вас таких тут много. Мне всё равно. Результат рабочий и полностью соответствует требованиям.

Comment: Я посмотрел, что к чему, конечно же. Получение значений из DOM в специализированных функциях - плохая практика. Функция `changeFirstSymbol` не должна получать значения из DOM, она должна менять первый символ :) Более подробно - в моем ответе.

Comment: А что вы будете делать, если на странице появится второй инпут, к которому надо будет такую же логику, как и к первому? Переписывать `changeFirstSymbol`?